# How to concatenate QuerySets from a list of QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I come across this syntax on stackoverflow

```
from itertools import chain 
result_list = list(chain(page_list, article_list, post_list))
```

I need to concatenate a bunch of QuerySets with something like this:

```
    prjExpList = list(chain(lvl for lvl in prjlvl))
    prjEnvList = list(chain(env for env in prjEnv))
```

This gives me an error of

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

My goal is to concatenate a bunch of QuerySets that's stored inside a list `prjlvl` and `prjEnv`
How do I do that?

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace?

Comment: Try `list(chain(prjlvl, prjEnv))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
prjExpList = list(chain.from_iterable(prjlvl))
```

Note that `itertools.chain()` takes a `*args` list of iterables, and that you can get the same unpacking behavior from the `chain.from_iterable()` class method.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: This is an overkill . Just using `list(queryset)` would work fine

Comment: My understanding is that `prjlvl` is a list of querysets.

Comment: `prjlvl` is indeed a list of querysets. This solution works!

Answer (score 2):

Are the QuerySets of the same model? You can just do

```
combined_queryset = queryset_1 | queryset_2 | queryset_3
```

To chain them together into one QuerySet. This means you can still do things with the QuerySet in the ORM, which is a big help.